# How to specific Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1platform in C++/CX

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx, windows-8.1-universal

I have the program in Runtime Component Project (Universal) to get Application ID,

```
Platform::Guid MyClass::getAppId()
{
#ifdef WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP
   return Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentApp::AppId;
#endif
}
```

After that I created a **Windows 8.1** Application and call the function, it should get error as I expect windows phone return back data only, however, it past the compilation, and I tried to use other macro from `winapifamily.h` and all failed.

So, how do I distinguish the target platform for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone App?

Comment: Use the #error directive to generate a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
   // This code is for Win32 desktop apps
#else
   // This code is for WinRT Windows Store apps
#endif

#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY) && WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP
  // This code is for Windows phone 8
#endif
```

[Reference: msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3965645c-978c-4148-b32c-1853f7fd22b3/platform-defined-macros-for-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithnativecode)